# Moto X (2nd generation) international travel

Tags: motorola, gsm

I want to get a motorola moto x (2nd generation) but I am unsure if the phone can work in other countries outside of the United States, specifically China.

Answer (score 0):

According to the spec sheets, YES, a Moto X 2014 will work in China *at 3G speeds*.

China provides access to their GSM network over the 2100MHz (HSPDA, or 3G) and 2500MHZ (LTE) spectrums, [shown here](http://www.worldtimezone.com/gsm.html). A Motorola Moto X (2nd Gen) purchased in the United States (from either Verizon or AT&T) covers that 2100MHz band for 3G, but doesn't touch the 2500MHz for LTE, [as seen here](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_x_(2nd_gen)-6649.php). In fact, the spec sheet shows it should work, *to some degree*, almost anywhere in the world that provides GSM service.